# SQL Query with MAX()Date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 month)

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, `Name` and `Termine`, with `Name.ID` as index on table 2 named `Termine.ID`.

I need a query that shows me the `Name` and the `Date` of table 2 where `Name.ID = Termine.ID`.

Finally I only need to see `Name` and `Date` when the last inserted `Date` is older than 6 months.

I've tried this:

```sql
SELECT Name.*, Termine.* FROM Name
LEFT JOIN Termine ON Name.ID = Termine.ID
WHERE (SELECT MAX(Termine.Datum) < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 month)FROM Termine)
```

Here are my tables.
Table named NAME

```
ID Name Vorname  
1  Test  Test  
2  Doe   John  
3  Mustermann Tony
```

And the Table called Termine

```
ID Datum    
2  12.03.2019  
1  26.09.2019  
3 24.08.2019  
1 12.02.2019  
3 01.01.2019  
2 01.02.2019
```

What i want to display at the end is:

```
ID Name  Vorname Datum  
2  Doe  John 12.03.2019
```

Because the Date 12.03.2019 is the last Date of ID 2 and older than 6 month from now.
Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - It always helps us when dealing with SQL questions if you can provide a sample of rows for each of your related tables together with a sample of what the query's output should be, given the sample tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THIS WORKED FINE!!!!

```
SELECT Name.*, Termine.* 
FROM Name 
INNER JOIN Termine ON Name.ID = Termine.ID 
WHERE DATE_SUB(Now(), INTERVAL 6 month) >=  ( 
        SELECT MAX(Termine.Datum) 
        FROM Termine 
        WHERE Name.ID = Termine.ID 
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use where clause this way

```
SELECT Name.*, Termine.* 
FROM Name
INNER JOIN Termine ON Name.ID = Termine.ID
AND Termine.Datum =  (
    SELECT max(Termine.Datum)
    FROM termine 
    where  Termine.Datum < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 month) )
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn´t work. Sorry. I´ve edited my Problem perhabs it is better to understand now?

Comment: what don you mean  "doesn´t work" .. you have error?  .. show me the exact error message ..  wrong result show me you actual result ... anyway answer  updated  for INNER JOIN  for obtain only the mathcing row

Comment: You are right. Thank You! With INNER JOIN it works, but i had to change the MAX into MIN to resolve the problem. Because the MAX function shows me the oldest date even if there is a younger. With MIN it shows the youngest Date. THANK YOU!!!!!

Comment: As i had filled the table i've seen that the query only shows the first item it gets and then the result stopped. After different tries i solved the problem like this            SELECT Beamte.*, Termine.* FROM Beamte INNER JOIN Termine ON Beamte.ID = Termine.ID WHERE DATE_SUB(Now(), INTERVAL 6 month) >= ( SELECT MAX(Termine.Datum) FROM Termine where Beamte.ID = Termine.ID )